# Trouble referencing logged in user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, railstutorial.org, friendly-id

I am new to Ruby on Rails I am using Michael Hartl's tutorial on RoR and trying to add Paperclip to do profile pictures for users. I am also using Friendly_Id on the users if that helps.

I get this error for one of my views. I am not sure why it is saying I am missing required keys, shouldn't @signed_in_user already reference the current signed in user object?

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Offending line in the view is

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@signed_in_user.avatar.url(:thumb), class:"profile_picture"), user_url %>
```

The controller that calls it is StoriesController#create: (Stories is basically the same as microposts a lá his tutorial)

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

def create
  if signed_in?
    @signed_in_user = self.current_user
    @story = current_user.stories.build
  end
  if @story.save
    flash[:success] = "Story Created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'users/show'
  end
end
```

The SessionsHelper that has methods being used above:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def signed_in_user

    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please Sign in."
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two different semantics. Either you use

```
link_to image_tag(...), @signed_in_user
```

or you use

```
link_to image_tag(...), user_url(@signed_in_user)
```

(or user_path(user) )

Currently you're using the second option, but without the user, that's what the error is complaining about: "missing required keys: [id]"

Comment: Using "link_to image_tag(...), user"

gives me an "undefined local variable or method `user'"

Comment: try this
<%= link_to image_tag(@signed_in_user.avatar.url(:thumb), class:"profile_picture"), user_url(@signed_in_user) %>

Comment: I modified the answer to more reflect your case